# Why can't you inherit PHP namespace aliases from included files?

Tags: php, namespaces

From the note on http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

So this means now I have to hard code/redeclare my namespaces in every file or always use the fully qualified namespace.

1. Why is this? Is it because the point of namespaces are they should never/hardly ever change?
2. Would it be considered a bad idea to store the aliasing code in a string and use eval()? Seems a dirty way of doing it so probably yes.
3. Do most developers declare oft-used objects (e.g. database) in a bootstrap to minimise rewriting aliasing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Namespaces are supposed to show the dependencies of a particular class, the downside you get with inheriting, is a class can have use statements that are never used in the class.
2. Yes, that would be a bad idea, `eval()` is a dirty dirty thing, that should be avoided at all costs
3. You dont need a namespace in the rest of your files if the DB is already initialized, goes the same with any initialized class
   of your files if the DB is already initialized, goes the same with any initialized class